# How to open up lucene files in windows?

Tags: windows

I received  several DVDs today containing several folders with cfx, CFS and segments files.

There is a setup Linux binary that does that work in Ubuntu. Googling I found out that this is of the lucene file format.

How do I open Lucene files in Windows?

Comment: I don't have anything to test it with, but luke seems to be java based, and can open [lucerne indexes](http://code.google.com/p/luke/source/browse/wiki/img/overview.png) and is probably your best bet here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Luke is the best tool to open Lucene indexes. Last version of Luke is available at https://java.net/projects/opengrok/downloads.